# Populating entity fields programmatically

Tags: entities

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['start_date'] = [
    '#type' => 'datetime',
    '#title' => $this->t('Start Date'),
    '#required' => TRUE, 
  ];
  $form['end_date'] = [
    '#type' => 'datetime',
    '#title' => $this->t('End Date'),
    '#required' => TRUE
  ];
  $form['location'] = [
    '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
    '#target_type' => 'node',
    '#selection_handler' => 'default',
    '#selection_settings' => ['target_bundles' => ['location']],
    '#title' => $this->t('Location'),
  ];
  $form['show'] = [
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Create Event'),
  ];
  return $form;
}

/**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $values = $form_state->getValues();
  $location = $form_state->getValue('location');
  $sd = $form_state->getValue('start_date');
  $sd = $sd->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  if($location == 1){
    $loc = "ASCET SE Center";
  }
  $node = Node::create(array(
    'type' => 'event',
    'title' =>  $sd . " " . $form_state->getValue('location'),
    'langcode' => 'en',
    'uid' => '1',
    'status' => 1,
    'field_location' => $loc,
    'field_start_date' => $sd,
  ));
```

I'm attempting to populate fields within the content type (event).   The Event node type has a start date, end date, and an entity reference to a Location content type. When passing the `$loc` I get a message that says:

*"InvalidArgumentException: Value is not a valid entity. in Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\DataType\EntityReference->setValue()"*

When I pass `$sd` as a string it doesn't populate. When I pass `$sd` as `$form_state->getValue('start_date');` it says that there is too much data to put into the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the ID of the referenced entity in the `target_id` column for the entity reference field, and `value` column for the timestamp field. Something like:

```
$target_id = $form_state->getValue('location');
$date = $form_state->getValue('start_date')->getTimestamp();

$node = Node::create(array(
  'type' => 'event',
  'title' =>  $sd . " " . $form_state->getValue('location'),
  'langcode' => 'en',
  'uid' => '1',
  'status' => 1,
  'field_location' => [
    'target_id' => $target_id,
  ],
  'field_start_date' => [
    'value' => $date,
  ],
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Clive.  However, this doesn't seem to be working for me still.   InvalidArgumentException: No entity type was provided, value is not a valid entity. is the message I receive for the location, and the date just simply doesn't populate.    Thoughts?

Comment: I haven't tried the entity reference one, but that's definitely the column name so it should work in theory. The date one I've tried as recently as this morning in my own code and it woks fine for me (using 8.4). You are calling `->save()` on the `$node` object after creation yeah? And what line is throwing the invalid arg exception?

Comment: It appears that line 72 is causing the error which is the 'target_id' => $target_id line. I am calling $node->save().   The node will create if I comment out the field_location array, however it doesn't populate the date information.

Comment: Ok...just a hunch, try `'field_location' => $form_state->getValue('location')` instead

Comment: Actually no, try `'field_location' => [$target_id]`. It's rather confusing

Comment: Awesome the 'field_location' => [$target_id] sorta worked.   Now to get the date working!    Thanks Clive, you've been a great help!